# Visual Studio Code Theme Edit PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, themes

I'm in the process of switching over to VS Code from Notepad++

The number one thing bugging me at the moment is in a file a PHP tag is the same colour coding as a DIV element. I'd like to change the colour of the PHP tags to be some shade of red.

Just using the default VS Dark theme.

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also make this change in your user settings. I included some additional customizations I use to bold function, keywords, etc... These types of changes should be placed in the user settings file rather than customizing a specific theme file - since your changes will be lost when the theme is upgraded.

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php",
                    "punctuation.section.embedded.end.php"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "keyword",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "storage",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "constant.language",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "support.class.builtin",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, provided me with more than i was after, simply copying these into my user settings change my tags to red and also added some other cool things

Answer (score 1):

As far as the themes, VS Code is every bit editable.

The file you are looking for is at :

> Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes

on Windows and search for file name `dark_vs.json` to locate it on any other system.

The section you'd want to change is this :

```
{
    "scope": [
        "punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php",
        "punctuation.section.embedded.end.php"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#569cd6"
    }
}
```

Feel free to chante the `foreground` color to whatever you'd like. You can, as well, modify any other color you'd like.