# How can I enable PHP Syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I use MAMP (on windows) as a local web server and I just started to use Visual Studio Code. I set the php.exe path in the settings.json file trough "php.validate.executablePath". It seems work, or maybe it gives me no error, so I think it's working, but the PHP syntax highlighting doesn't work. All my variables are white colored and so the functions.

What could be the problem?

Thank you all.

EDIT:
Ok, this was a theme problem and the highlighting started to work properly, but my "`<?php ?>`" tags inside the html code look the same color as other tags. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: By Default VS Code provides syntax highlighting but your file extension have to be valid PHP file formats such as .php or .phtml

Comment: They are, but I was just using a theme that (I don't know why) didn't do the highlight. Now my only problem is the one that involves the php tags.

Comment: By changing theme, highlighting works?

Comment: I get rid of this problem too. Using this code found in another question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948893/visual-studio-code-theme-edit-php

Comment: My file is a .php file, but it consists, mostly, of HTML with a few `<?=..?>` or `<?php .. ?>` inserts. If I choose "Language Mode = HTML"  -- I get all the HTML highlighted, but PHP inserts are not. on top of that - these PHP inserts are underlined as errors sometimes… If I choose PHP mode - everything outside PHP becomes single colored =)

Answer (score 23):

Make sure you didn't forget your

```
<?php ... ?>
```

tags